# Read Access Violation this was nullptr error, initilized incorrectly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, uwp, c++-cx

I am writing a program in C++/CX using the universal windows platform (UWP). I am new at programming and more familiar with regular C++. This is my first time making a UWP app.

The program contains a class called Dress_pack and I have created an instance of it called d in my MainPage.xaml.cpp file.

`Dress_pack d ("","","");`

Dress_pack has a member called meas_v which is an IVector of type Platform::String^. Here is my Dress_pack class constructor:

```
Dress_pack::Dress_pack(Platform::String^ plant = "", Platform::String^    prog = "", Platform::String^ robot = ""){
plant_no = plant; 
prog_no = prog;
robot_no = robot;
Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Platform::String^>^ meas_v = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Platform::String^>^ iss_dis_v = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();}
```

Later in my MainPage.xaml.cpp file I try to append a string to this vector like this:

```
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include "dress_pack.h"
Dress_pack d ("","","");

MainPage::MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
d.meas_v->Append("dk");
}
```

My MainPage.xaml.h looks like:

```
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace Project_1
{

public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
    MainPage();

};  

}
```

My header for Dress_pack contains:

```
#pragma once
ref class Dress_pack sealed
{

public:
    property Platform::String^ plant_no;
    property Platform::String^ prog_no;
    property Platform::String^ robot_no;
    property Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Platform::String^>^ meas_v; property Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<Platform::String^>^ iss_dis_v;

//constructor
Dress_pack(Platform::String^ plant, Platform::String^ prog, Platform::String^ robot);

};
```

But during runtime, the error `Exception thrown: read access violation this was nullptr` occurs on `d.meas_v->Append("dk");`.

During debug, I can see that meas_v contains value nullptr which seems to be the source of the issue. I'm not sure why this is though. Have I initialized my vector incorrectly? Is it some other issue? A push in the right direction would help. Also let me know if you need me to post more code to understand the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Source code is usually easier and quicker to parse than an explanation of what the code looks like.

Comment: `ref new` means that this pointer is being reference-counted (and therefore garbage collected) - you do not call `delete[]` on it

Comment: I don't think that you're supposed to `delete` managed objects. In particular, `delete[]` on an `IVector` looks very wrong.

Comment: Oh! Alright, I have removed my destructor. Thank you. The original problem still remains.

Comment: Without seeing a [mcve] we cannot help you. (Also you should be able to find out what exactly is causing the exception to be thrown by debugging your code)

Comment: I have added all I can think to add without adding irrelevant things.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you create two new local variables that happen to have the same names as your fields.

Also, you should use `L"bla"` strings for `Platform::String` (with the `L` prefix to force UCS2).